# My linear program has multiple optimal solutions. I want that corner point at which the value of one of the variables is the maximum?

Tags: linear-programming

Is there a way to find the optimal point with this special property in polynomial time? Note that the polytope in the linear program may be unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose minimization.

1. Solve the original LP problem, yielding optimal objective value $z^*$.
2. Introduce an objective cut $z \le z^*$.
3. Solve the new LP problem with the objective of maximizing the specified variable $x_j$.

LP is polynomial, and the process above involves solving two LPs of essentially the same size.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work as the new LP can be unbounded. Is there a way to limit the search only to the vertices?

Comment: OK, I see that my suggestion can fail in the unbounded case, even with two variables: minimize $-x_1$ subject to $0\le x_1\le 1$ and $x_2\ge 0$, and then you want to maximize $x_2$ subject to $x_1=1$ and $x_2\ge 0$, which is unbounded. But if you also restrict to the only extreme point $(1,0)$, the problem is bounded.